# WebAPI - using Unity with Ioc across multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have a solution with multiple projects - similar to below:

- WebAPI

  - ICustomerService.cs
- Business Logic

  - CustomerService.cs
  - IDatabaseService.cs
- Database Access

  - DatabaseService.cs

Previously the WebAPI project had a reference to the business logic, then that had a reference to database access.  I am trying to invert this logic.

Currently, I am using Unity in my WebAPI project to resolve the interfaces with implementations from the business logic layer, however once I have inverted my logic so that the business logic layer has a reference to the WebAPI layer the Unity registration doesn't work without a circular reference:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

When I am trying to register my types, the ICustomerService lives in the top project, CustomerService is invisible to it.

I have read about having a separate project to house the unity configuration but that would create a circular reference also.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wanna invert that? Seems to me like the only way of doing it. The WebAPI project is the main entrance (if it was self-hosted, it would contain a programs.cs). This project would also contain your composition root for setting up dependency injection and resolving types (this is handled by the WebAPI). See also [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Could you explain to me the benefit of doing this?

Also be aware that it is bad practice to spread out the IoC container cross projects. Only the composition root (main) should know about the fact that Unity is being used. Also avoid using the ServiceLocator pattern.

The objects in the different projects should just have a reference/dependency through for example the constructor.

If you think about it like that the `Controller` is dependent on `ICustomService`, `CustomerService` is dependent on `IDatabaseService`.

Also a note: I would put the implementation and interface in the same projects.

**WebAPI**

- Controller

**Business Logic**

- ICustomerService.cs
- CustomerService.cs

**Database Access**

- IDatabaseService.cs
- DatabaseService.cs

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the reason i wanted to do it is to support flexibility of the business logic and below layers.  I am putting this on top of an ERP system which is changing, and both systems will parallel run for a while.  I wanted the dependency injector to be intelligent so as services are moved from one system to the other, i could put logic in place to know "you use CustomerServiceA.cs" and "you use CustomerServiceB.cs" - maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: So you want to be able to change the Business logic layer without recompiling?

Comment: There will be a second business logic and database access layer soon, i was hoping to be able to choose which one i want to use programmatically, but the webapi shouldn't know which implementation its going to be using

Comment: Typical you would use something like an XML configuration to do this. See [XML configuraiont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507504(v=pandp.30).aspx). If this is a requirement you should not have the implementation and interface in the same dll. I can also recommend this book: [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1935182501/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1935182501&linkCode=as2&tag=ploeh-20)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. Your controller should inject the icustomerservice implementation in the constructor and the service should inject the idatabaseservice in its constructor.

```
public FooController(ICustomerService svc)
...
public CustomerService(IDatabaseService db)
...
```

And add the database DI config

```
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
```

When you are ready to use the new implementation, just change the reference in the config to instantiate the new implementation.

The interfaces should be in a project together and the implementation should be in a project together. The new and old implementation should share a common interface.